# How to handle all ValidationException that would answer contained Problem Details

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Tell me how to build a handler for ValidationException to answer details problem like this:

```
"errors": {
    "Password": [
      "The field password must be a string or massive type with a maximum length of '1'."
    ]
  },
  "title": "one or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400
```

For example, the input contains an error and the PhoneNumber class can not be created and throws a ValidationException("PhoneNumber is not correct"), and that would be in response:

```
  "errors": {
    "PhoneNumber": [
      "PhoneNumber is not correct."
    ]
  },
  "title": "one or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400
```

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP Core follows the HTTP Standard way of doing things. This includes providing Status Codes like [422](https://httpstatuses.com/422) and error messages in [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) format, for [validation errors](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/#problem-details).

Its best to have it that way, so that all the other tools/API/frameworks will understand it. However, if you have a real need to change the default behaviour, you need to look into customizing [`BadRequestObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  object. You can [see here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/validation-response-aspnet-core-webapi/) for an example of how to do that.